# Javascript jslint says spell_img is used before being declared

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with my code, I checked it with an online jslint and it says spell_img is used before being declared?

```
spell_img = new Image();
spell_img.src = '/images/standard/spellcheck.gif';
spell_img.setAttribute('title',_lang_spellcheck );

function find_text_boxes()
{
    myforms = document.forms;
    for( i=0;i < myforms.length; i++ )
    {
        textareas = myforms[i].getElementsById('textarea');
        for( y=0; y < textareas.length; y++ )
        {
            spelllink = document.createElement('a');
            spelllink.setAttribute('href',"javascript:spellCheck(" + i + ", '" + textareas[y].name + "')");
            spelllink.appendChild( spell_img.cloneNode(true) );
            textareaParent = textareas[y].parentNode;
            textareaParent.insertBefore( spelllink, textareas[y].nextSibling );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly because `spell_img` is a global variable

Comment: Yeah, um, you’re not declaring anything.

Comment: var spell_img="";

place this right at the top of your scope.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new. What am I missing?

Comment: You've missed [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: declare variables. In JavaScript, this is done using `var`. `var` scopes the variable to the scope where the `var` was found; scopes in JavaScript are (currently) function-based.

```
var spell_img = new Image();
spell_img.src = '/images/standard/spellcheck.gif';
spell_img.setAttribute('title',_lang_spellcheck );

function find_text_boxes()
{
    var myforms = document.forms;
    for( var i=0;i < myforms.length; i++ )
    {
        var textareas = myforms[i].getElementsById('textarea');
        for( var y=0; y < textareas.length; y++ )
        {
            var spelllink = document.createElement('a');
            spelllink.setAttribute('href',"javascript:spellCheck(" + i + ", '" + textareas[y].name + "')");
            spelllink.appendChild( spell_img.cloneNode(true) );
            textareaParent = textareas[y].parentNode;
            textareaParent.insertBefore( spelllink, textareas[y].nextSibling );
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2: `getElementsById` is not a thing that exists. It’s `getElementsByTagName`.

```
var spell_img = new Image();
spell_img.src = '/images/standard/spellcheck.gif';
spell_img.setAttribute('title',_lang_spellcheck );

function find_text_boxes()
{
    var myforms = document.forms;

    for( var i = 0; i < myforms.length; i++ )
    {
        var textareas = myforms[i].getElementsByTagName('textarea');

        for( var y = 0; y < textareas.length; y++ )
        {
            var spelllink = document.createElement('a');
            spelllink.setAttribute('href',"javascript:spellCheck(" + i + ", '" + textareas[y].name + "')");
            spelllink.appendChild( spell_img.cloneNode(true) );
            textareaParent = textareas[y].parentNode;
            textareaParent.insertBefore( spelllink, textareas[y].nextSibling );
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3: wait, why are you even getting forms first?

```
var spell_img = new Image();
spell_img.src = '/images/standard/spellcheck.gif';
spell_img.setAttribute('title',_lang_spellcheck );

function find_text_boxes() {
    var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

    for(var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
        var spelllink = document.createElement('a');
        spelllink.setAttribute('href',"javascript:spellCheck(" + i + ", '" + textareas[y].name + "')");
        spelllink.appendChild( spell_img.cloneNode(true) );
        textareaParent = textareas[y].parentNode;
        textareaParent.insertBefore( spelllink, textareas[y].nextSibling );
    }
}
```

Step 4: `javascript:` URIs are bad. Inline JavaScript is bad. Inline JavaScript in inline URL in JavaScript? That’s really bad and is kind of like `eval` and all sorts of things. Create a function and make `spellCheck` accept an element *object*, not form index, yuck. `title` is a property as well as an attribute (like `src`), by the way:

```
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

var spell_img = new Image();
spell_img.src = '/images/standard/spellcheck.gif';
spell_img.title = _lang_spellcheck;

function find_text_boxes() {
    var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

    forEach.call(textareas, function(textarea) {
        var spellLink = document.createElement('a');

        spellLink.href = "#";
        spellLink.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            spellCheck(textarea);
        }, false);

        spellLink.appendChild(spell_img.cloneNode(true));

        textarea.parentNode.insertBefore(spelllink, textareas[y].nextSibling);
    });
}
```

If you need to be compatible with old IE without shivs, that’s doable:

```
var spell_img = new Image();
spell_img.src = '/images/standard/spellcheck.gif';
spell_img.title = _lang_spellcheck;

function find_text_boxes() {
    var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

    for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
        (function(textarea) {
            var spellLink = document.createElement('a');

            spellLink.href = "#";
            spellLink.onclick = function() {
                spellCheck(textarea);
                return false;
            };

            spellLink.appendChild(spell_img.cloneNode(true));

            textarea.parentNode.insertBefore(spelllink, textareas[y].nextSibling);
        })(textareas[i]);
    });
}
```

You can really put the cherry on top with some event delegation.

```
function addSpellLink(textarea) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.className = "spell-link";
    link.href = "#";

    link.appendChild(spell_img.cloneNode(true));

    textarea.parentNode.insertBefore(link, textarea.nextSibling);
}

function findTextboxes() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("textarea"), addSpellLink);
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("spell-link")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        spellCheck(e.previousElementSibling);
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: So lastly where will the image be inserted now?

Comment: this might be a tad bit more than a new guy can take in

Comment: @user2415940: What do you mean? Isn’t it in the same place?

Answer (score 0):

```
var spell_img = new Image();//place any one of these right at the top of your scope.
```

or

```
window.spell_img = new Image();//replace first line
```

Comment: should I also var spelllink, myforms, textareas, textarea parent?

Comment: Something is still wrong. hmmmm. is there anything else I should change on there?